# Rails 3 devise i need help with confermation

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I have watched the railscast on devise for some reason he pulled out the confrmation e-mail part so i have no idea how it works i have it up and running but what i need to know is dose it send an e-mail in development or not?

is there a way to force it to send the mail just to test it or can you enplane how to do it in the console!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it doesn't send email on development environment. You need to edit your `config/environments/development.rb` and add :

```
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }
```

Then look in your console running your server when it try to send an email you will see actually all what your need there (headers, title and body email)